# Setting up a remote Derby DB: "No suitable driver found" error

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am trying to set up a remote Derby database just for practice. The following code works without a problem whenever I access the DB on my harddrive:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
//        String dbPath = "C:/Java_Practice/derbyDB";    // this dbPath works...
        String dbPath = "//108.167.141.127/derbyDB";     // and this one doesn't
        String url = protocol + dbPath;
        try( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url) )
        {
            System.out.println(conn);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I then uploaded the whole derbyDB directory to my Hostgator-hosted website, obtained its IP by pinging the server and edited the dbPath var accordingly. The code stopped working as if it can't even see the DB. What am I missing?

Comment: "No suitable driver found" means that the Derby classes aren't in your CLASSPATH. Here's some docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/getstart/tgs26250.html

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton The thing is, the connection works properly when I access the DB that sits on my harddrive, which means that the CLASSPATH var is set up correctly. What doesn't work is the connection to the copy of the same DB that I uploaded to my website. I suspect that something is wrong with the dbPath var because replacing 'derbyDB' with an arbitrary name like 'xyz' generates the same SQLException...

Comment: If the database is on another machine, you have to run the Derby Network Server on that machine to service client-server requests to that machine. Try working your way through the tutorial that I linked to in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question after some digging**.
This is what I found in the official Apache Derby documentation (https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop14.html):

> You can specify only databases that are local to the machine on which
>   the JVM is running.

Looks like what I wanted to accomplish cannot be done...

Comment: The Derby 10.0 manual set is more than 10 years old; try reading the current documentation. And before you give up and conclude that it "cannot be done", perhaps you could try to precisely express what you wanted to accomplish. To start with, Derby supports both Embedded and Client-Server configurations. Which one are you attempting to use?

Comment: @ Bryan Pendleton   Thank you Bryan, I do appreciate your help. All I wanted to accomplish was to have more practice with a simulated real-world scenario as a part of preparation for my forthcoming OCP exam, nothing more. The OCP prep guide I'm using refers to Derby all the time, so the choice was just natural. Seeing that it can't be done in a snap, I switched to MySQL instead; everything is working as it should now. As for the documentation... Honestly, I had no idea it was *that* old :( The timestamp on the page said 'Last Published: 01/24/2013 '... Will be more careful next time.

Comment: No worries. Glad you were able to get your prep-work done. If you want to try Derby again sometime in the future, I hope you are able to.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your driver class not loaded.
Try loading it before calling DriverManager.getConnection, and see if it works.

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";
String dbPath = "//108.167.141.127/derbyDB"+";create=true";
String url = protocol + dbPath;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Comment: Explicit driver loading in a normal Java application hasn't been necessary since Java 6 (JDBC 4), assuming the driver is JDBC 4 compliant and on the initial application classpath.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. My DB's driver *is* JDBC 4 compliant. The DB itself is fully accessible, traversable and updatable --- but only when it lives on my system. When it's remote - no go.